# How do I return a byte array from an action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I return a byte array from an action? It is not an image, not a PDF, not a file, just a byte array. The client is a device, which does not treat it as anything except for a byte array. It's firmware just read this byte array byte by byte.

Comment: There really isn't such a thing as a `byte array`, it still has to be wrapped into an http response...  Images, pdfs and files are all byte arrays wrapped in an http reponse.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using the File helper or use a FileContentResult.  I believe the content type application/octet-stream is for generic binary data:

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = null; // assign bytes
    return File(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

Comment: the first File argument should be `fileBytes` instead of `bytes`